# How to extract substrings without regular expressions

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a text and want to extract all substrings from it that are between `@begin = 'Some Text1'` and `@end = 'Some Text2'`. Regex makes this task as complicated as possible. Is there a simple function in Ruby like this?

```
def substrings (text2SearchIn, begin, end)
  returns array of results
end
```

Comment: simplest I can think of is regex itself

Comment: using regex: `str[/#{@begin}(.*?)#{@end}/m, 1]`

Comment: it returns a string! Why whould I need a string?

Comment: It returns the substring between two patterns. Once you have it you can do `split` to convert it into array, or similar operations. Though I do not have answer for why would you need any particular data structure.

Comment: What is complicated with `str.scan /(?<=#{@begin}).*?(?=#{@end})/`?

Comment: "Regex has been invented to make this task as complicated as possible.". No, it wasn't. Regex are extremely flexible and powerful, and terribly overused when people first encounter them, and they're only as complicated as someone wants to make them. Simple ones are extremely powerful and very easy to learn.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". We need a better example of your input data and what you expect from it and what you've tried writing.

Comment: Judging from your English skills, I am not sure if you really intend what you wrote.  "All substrings between ...A and B" implies that there are multiple (ways to take) substrings. For example, if you have string `"fooAbarAbazBbooB"`, then your substrings would be `"baz"`, `"barAbaz"`, `"bazBboo"`. Is this what you mean?

Comment: I assume your comment, `"it returns a string!...`, was directed at shivam. shivam, however, will not necessarily be notified by SO if you don't include '@shivam' in the text.

Answer (score 2):

This is painful when it's so easy to do with a regex, but if you must, here's a non-regex solution:

```
str = "Now is the time @begin to see @end where @begin things @end stand."

append = nil
str.split.each_with_object([]) do |word, arr|
  case word
  when "@begin"
    append = [] unless append
  when "@end"
    arr << append unless append.nil? || append.empty?
    append = nil
  else
    append << word if append
  end
end.map { |arr| arr.join(' ') }
  #=> ["to see", "things"]
```

The steps:

```
append = nil
b = str.split
  #=> ["Now", "is", "the", "time", "@begin", "to", "see", "@end", "where",
  #    "@begin", "things", "@end", "stand."] 
c = b.each_with_object([]) do |word, arr|
  puts "word=#{word}, arr=#{arr}, append=#{append ? append : 'nil'}"
  case word
  when "@begin"
    append = [] unless append
    puts "  append set to []" unless append
  when "@end"
    puts "  #{arr} << #{append}" unless append.nil? || append.empty?
    arr << append unless append.nil? || append.empty?
    append = nil
    puts "  Now arr=#{arr}" unless append.nil? || append.empty?        
    puts "  append set to nil"
  else
    append << word if append
    puts "  '#{ word }' #{ append ? "added to append: append=#{append}" : "skipped" }"
  end
end
  #=> [["to", "see"], ["things"]]
c.map { |arr| arr.join(' ') }
  #=> ["to see", "things"]
```

The printed messages:

```
word=Now, arr=[], append=nil
  'Now' skipped
word=is, arr=[], append=nil
  'is' skipped
word=the, arr=[], append=nil
  'the' skipped
word=time, arr=[], append=nil
  'time' skipped
word=@begin, arr=[], append=nil
  append set to []
word=to, arr=[], append=[]
  'to' added to append: append=["to"]
word=see, arr=[], append=["to"]
  'see' added to append: append=["to", "see"]
word=@end, arr=[], append=["to", "see"]
  [] << ["to", "see"]
  append set to nil
word=where, arr=[["to", "see"]], append=nil
  'where' skipped
word=@begin, arr=[["to", "see"]], append=nil
  append set to []
word=things, arr=[["to", "see"]], append=[]
  'things' added to append: append=["things"]
word=@end, arr=[["to", "see"]], append=["things"]
  [["to", "see"]] << ["things"]
  append set to nil
word=stand., arr=[["to", "see"], ["things"]], append=nil
  'stand.' skipped
```

Note:

```
str = "I @begin to see @end where @begin things @end stand @begin to reason."
  #=> ["to see", "things"]
str = "I @begin to see @end where @end and @begin things @end stand to reason."
  #=> ["to see", "things"]
str = "I @begin to see @begin where @end and things @end stand to reason."
  #=> ["to see where"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [String#index](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-index) and a loop:

```
def substrings(text, begin_string, end_string)
  offset = 0
  strings = []
  while start_offset = text.index(begin_string, offset)
    contents_offset = start_offset + begin_string.size
    end_offset = text.index(end_string, contents_offset)
    strings << text[contents_offset...end_offset]
    offset = end_offset + end_string.size
  end
  strings
end

str = "1(2)34(5)()"
p substrings(str, "(", ")")  # => ["2", "5", ""]
```

As you can see, Cary Swoveland and I came up with different answers.  His answer treats spaces specially and splits on them.  Since your question did not provide sample input and output, it is hard to judge which answer is better.

Comment: Since the question doesn't provide sample input or output it's probably better to request that the OP fixes the question so it's more clear what is wanted. As is it's not clear.

Comment: @theTinMan, on the other hand, you could argue that readers, including the OP, are getting two for the price of one.

Comment: It may be nothing to worry about, but there would be a problem if each  `begin_string` did not have a matching `end_sting`, or vice-versa, or if pairs of markers were nested, etc.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, it's not a matter of needing volume, it's a matter of needing answers that are to the point of the question, and that point is not defined well. Questions and answers aren't merely for the asker, they're also for people searching for the solution in the future. Poorly asked questions dilute SO. Well asked questions let us point to them and say "There's your answer along with alternate ideas."